# SSRS date to and From parameters default to current financial year

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I have a Dynamics CRM SSRS report which has two date parameters to filter records when report is executed.
When running the report I would like the parameters to default to the current financial year eg. if today is `01/10/2017` then `From` should default to `01/04/2016` and `To` should default to `31/03/2017`.

Can this be done and if so what is the best way?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table with your company's important dates on it?

Comment: If not, I'd recommend creating one and querying it to retrieve the default dates. -https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/

Comment: If from & to date has to be calculated this way, no need to be parameterized in report. Instead, you can have this manipulation in your query itself.

Comment: User will still need ability to change dates if ever required

Comment: If you have the calendar table you can add a dataset for Begin and End dates based on today's date, then assign those values as default values for the parameters. This way the parameters are defaulted to the correct dates but at the same time they can also change the dates.

Comment: Is there no way to set default values using expressions?

Comment: Are you able to use sql datasets for these parameters or do they have to be expressions?

Comment: Ideally expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why people are over complicating this. I understand the common need for date tables, I use them a lot but it's pretty easy to do in an expression.

The From date expression needs to be

```
=DATESERIAL(Year(Now()) - (IIF(format(now(),"MMdd") > "0331",0,1))  ,4,1)
```

and the to date expression needs to be

```
=DATESERIAL(Year(Now()) + (IIF(format(now(),"MMdd") > "0331",1,0))  ,3,31)
```

All we are doing is creating a date value that is either 1st April current year or 31st March current year then depending on if the current date is on or before the 31st March we adjust the year by 1.

**I'M ASSUMING YOUR DATES ARE WRONG IN YOUR EXAMPLE**. You said you wanted current financial year but your sample showed last financial year. Anyway, if the code above is incorrect just adjust the `Year(Now())` to be `(Year(Now())-1)` .